# Getting edges to curve around other nodes

Tags: nodes, arrows

I'm trying to draw a state transition model, and I'm having trouble getting the edges to going under a node instead of across it and other edges along the way. I've tried experimenting with in/out options but this is the best so far. What other options should I be looking into?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=5cm,
thick,main node/.style={circle,
fill=blue!20,draw,thick,align=center}]
\node[main node] (1) {$M$ \\ $P_{x_i, y_j}$};
\node[main node] (2) [below right of=1]{$I_{y}$ \\ $q_{x_i}$};
\node[main node] (3) [above right of=1]{$I_{x}$ \\ $q_{y_j}$};
\node[main node] (4) [left of=1]{\(B\)};
\node[main node] (5) [below right of=3]{\(E\)};
\path[]
  (1) edge [loop left, thick] node {$1-2\delta-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick, bend right] node[above] {$\delta$} (2)
      edge [thick, bend left] node[below] {$\delta$} (3)
      edge [thick] node[above]{$\tau$} (5)
  (2) edge [loop right, thick] node[right] {$\epsilon$} (2)
      edge [thick, bend right] node[above, rotate=-45] {$1-\epsilon-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick] node[above, rotate=60] {$\tau$} (5)
  (3) edge [loop right, thick] node[right] {$\epsilon$} (3)
      edge [thick, bend left] node[below, rotate=45] {$1-\epsilon-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick] node[above, rotate=120] {$\tau$} (5)
  (4) edge [thick, out=-90, in=-90] node[below] {$\tau$} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `looseness` parameter or some others which are explained in [section "70.3 Curves" from pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=753)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=5cm,
thick,main node/.style={circle,
fill=blue!20,draw,thick,align=center}]
\node[main node] (1) {$M$ \\ $P_{x_i, y_j}$};
\node[main node] (2) [below right of=1]{$I_{y}$ \\ $q_{x_i}$};
\node[main node] (3) [above right of=1]{$I_{x}$ \\ $q_{y_j}$};
\node[main node] (4) [left of=1]{\(B\)};
\node[main node] (5) [below right of=3]{\(E\)};
\path[]
  (1) edge [loop left, thick] node {$1-2\delta-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick, bend right] node[above] {$\delta$} (2)
      edge [thick, bend left] node[below] {$\delta$} (3)
      edge [thick] node[above]{$\tau$} (5)
  (2) edge [loop right, thick] node[right] {$\epsilon$} (2)
      edge [thick, bend right] node[above, rotate=-45] {$1-\epsilon-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick] node[above, rotate=60] {$\tau$} (5)
  (3) edge [loop right, thick] node[right] {$\epsilon$} (3)
      edge [thick, bend left] node[below, rotate=45] {$1-\epsilon-\tau$} (1)
      edge [thick] node[above, rotate=120] {$\tau$} (5)
  (4) edge [thick, out=-90, in=-90, looseness=1.5] node[below] {$\tau$} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, thank you!